# Lubuntu 18.10 panel position error (Openbox margins)

Tags: lubuntu, panel, openbox, 18.10

Noob here with Lubuntu 18.10.  I set up a desktop with two panels - one at the lower display edge with several widgets and another at the upper display edge with just a Task Manager widget. All works OK but when I reboot the PC the upper edge panel appears across the middle of the display.

Additional information in  response to questions asked:

1) Problem occurs with fresh install on laptop and desktop.
2) Laptop screen size is 1366x768. Desktop screen size is 1920x1080.
3) Problem still occurs with sudo service sddm restart

A chance discovery showed a connection between this problem and the "Margin" values in Openbox settings. Experiment showed that it occurs if (and only if) the top and bottom edge margins are *both* set to values greater than or equal to the "Size" of their corresponding panels. If either of those margins is set to a value less than the corresponding panel size then the problem does not arise. Unfortunately that is not really an "answer", because for clarity I want top and bottom edge Margins that are *both* at least two pixels *greater* than the panel Sizes that I am using.

A similar problem occurs when the panels are put at the sides of the display. I have not yet determined the exact margin sizes that cause that to happen.

What must I do if I want to use top and bottom edge margins that are larger than the Panel Sizes?

Comment: Welcome to Ask (L)Ubuntu! That does certainly sound like an interesting race condition. Can you consistently reproduce it? If so, can I get a screenshot?

Comment: The condition is consistent and occurs in an identical way on my laptop and on my desktop PC. I'm new to Lubuntu but will send you a screenshot as soon as I can figure out how to make one if you tell me how I can contact you. But that said I can assure you that the problem is exactly as described - what should be the "upper edge" panel (with just a Task Manager widget) appears half way up the screen instead of at the top edge. (Note that I'm using "Ambiance" theme in LXQt appearance as that seems to be the only one that gives distinct button "borders" on the Task Manager buttons).

Comment: 3 questions: 1. new install or upgrade? 2. screen size? 3. does this reoccur if you `sudo service sddm restart` rather than just reboot? Also maybe post up your `$HOME/.config/lxqt/panel.conf`, too.